# ActiveAdmin batch_action how to custom form and execute js code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to use ActiveAdmin batch_action, but also want to custom form to design the field, and can execute js, to change the feild select data. And ActiveAdmin batch_action acccording to the documention to configure the batch_action form, when I click the button,
this form haven't submit button.

Comment: The modal holding the form for your batch action that you specify using ActiveAdmin's dsl is not very customizable. Can you post more source code, it is hard to be of any help.